# Adding a TCP Printer with Powershell

Tags: powershell

We have several locations with different IP configs, there is one printer at each of the locations. I want one script to install them all. Separately that is.

They should run the script on each of the locations to install the printer there.

The printers are all `HP LaserJetPro MFP M130nw`, I want my coworkers to be prompted to enter the IP Address of the printer (shown on each printers screen), they should be prompted to enter the name of the location - which would become the name of the printer.

Also it needs to be elevated but the users don't have administrative accounts so it needs to be implemented into the script.

EDIT:
Here are two versions of scripts I tried:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
Start-Sleep -seconds 5
$IPAddress = -Prompt 'Vul het IP Adress in wat op het schermpje van de printer staat, bv. 192.168.1.110'
$PrinterName = -Prompt 'Vul hier de naam van de Inloop in, bv. Gerrenbroek'
Add-PrinterDriver -Name $PrinterName -DeviceURL $IPAdress
```

And this is a script I found somewhere, but I can't get it to take my info..

```
 <#
.SYNOPSIS
Add a Network Printer connection, optionally making it the default printer.

.DESCRIPTION
Uses a COM object to add a Network Printer, and optionally sets that printer
as the default. If an error is encountered, the exception is written to a
file called Add-NetworkPrinter.err in the current $env:temp directory, and                             
then
the script terminates.

.PARAMETER PrinterShare
The UNC path to the shared printer.
e.g. \\printers1.campus.ad.uvm.edu\ETS-SAA-SamsungML-3560

.PARAMETER Default
Specifies that the printer will also be set as the default printer for the                     
current user.

.EXAMPLE
Add-NetworkPrinter.ps1 -PrinterShare '\\ETS-SAA-SamsungML-3560' -Default

.NOTES
    Script Name: Add-NetworkPrinter.ps1

#>


[cmdletbinding()]

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Enter the UNC path to the network printer")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $PrinterShare,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch] $Default
)

Set-PSDebug -Strict

$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"out-file:Encoding"="ASCII"}

$ws_net = New-Object -COM WScript.Network

write-verbose "Adding connection to $PrinterShare"
try {
    $ws_net.AddWindowsPrinterConnection($PrinterShare)
}
catch {
    $error[0].exception | out-file (join-path $env:temp 'Add-        
NetworkPrinter.err')
    throw $error[0]
}

write-verbose "Setting the printer as the default"
if ( $Default ) {
    try {
        $ws_net.SetDefaultPrinter($PrinterShare)
    }
    catch {
        $error[0].exception | out-file (join-path $env:temp 'Add-            
NetworkPrinter.err')
        throw $error[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense but sounds like you are too. Most people here will tell you to visit www.pleasewritescriptforme.com. Myself being new here will display much more patience. So, i would suggest you to look up this simple cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/add-printer?view=win10-ps

Also, a script cannot bypass elevated privileges as it runs in the context of the user who runs it. Only way you can do it is somehow hardcoding the credentials of an elevated user. Not a good idea for an open script.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added what I got so far.. I trid it and couldn't get it to work, I'll edit my post!